# How to "zip" lists in tcl

Tags: list, tcl

I have three lists :

```
set l1 {1 2 3}
set l2 {'one' 'two' 'three'}
set l3 {'uno' 'dos' 'tres'}
```

and I would like to build this list :

```
{{1 'one' 'uno'} {2 'two' 'dos'} {3 'three' 'tres'}}
```

In `python`, I would use something like the built-in function `zip`. What should I do in `tcl` ? I have looked in the [documentation of 'concat'](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1037), but
haven't find a priori relevant commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not yet on Tcl 8.6 (where you can use `lmap`) you need this:

```
set zipped {}
foreach a $l1 b $l2 c $l3 {
    lappend zipped [list $a $b $c]
}
```

That's effectively what `lmap` does for you, but it was a new feature in 8.6.

Answer (score 5):

```
lmap a $l1 b $l2 c $l3 {list $a $b $c}
```

List map, `lmap`, is a mapping command that takes elements from one or more lists and executes a script. It creates a new list where each element is the result of one execution of the script.

Documentation: [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm)

This command was added in Tcl 8.6, but can easily be added to earlier versions.

[Getting `lmap` for Tcl 8.5 and earlier](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version that takes an arbitrary number of list names:

```
set l1 {a b c}
set l2 {d e f}
set l3 {g h i j}

proc zip args {
    foreach l $args {
        upvar 1 $l $l
        lappend vars [incr n]
        lappend foreach_args $n [set $l]
    }
    foreach {*}$foreach_args {
        set elem [list]
        foreach v $vars {
            lappend elem [set $v]
        }
        lappend result $elem
    }
    return $result
}

zip l1 l2 l3
```

```
{a d g} {b e h} {c f i} {{} {} j}
```

Requires Tcl 8.5 for the `{*}` argument expansion.

An 8.6 version

```
proc zip args {
    foreach l $args {
        upvar 1 $l $l
        lappend vars [incr n]
        lappend lmap_args $n [set $l]
    }
    lmap {*}$lmap_args {lmap v $vars {set $v}}
}
```